# How to open excel worksheet on aspose cell in existing excel template and write new excel worksheets on existing excel template using asp.net with c#

Tags: asp.net, excel, aspose

How can i open excel worksheet on aspose cell in existing excel template and write new excel worksheets on existing excel template using asp.net with c# ? kindly give me an examples...

Thanks and regards,
Parthiban K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your last comment, you can import the data from a datatable (dataset) to a new worksheet in an existing workbook using the following code sample:

```
//Open the existing workbook
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("book1.xls");

//add new worksheet other than the existing worksheets
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("New Sheet");

//import data from datatable (dataset) to newly created worksheet
//dataTable is the dataset table
worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dataTable, true, "A1");

//save the updated workbook
workbook.Save("book1.xls");
```

Answer (score 1):

I work as social media developer at Aspose. Use the following sample code to open an existing excel file and add worksheet to it.

```
//open the template excel file
Workbook wb = new Workbook("input.xls");

//Add new worksheet in existing workbook
Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("New Sheet");

//Access the "A1" cell in the sheet.
Cell cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];

//Input the "Hello World!" text into the "A1" cell
cell.PutValue("Hello World!");

//Save the Excel file.
wb.Save("output.xls");
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another doubt... How can i write dataset values in to new excel worksheet on already exists workbook(It contains two worksheet) using asp.net with c#?

Comment: Replied to your query as a new answer as it contained code segment. Do let me know if you need any further assistance.